# Dynamic Page Replacing Content

Tags: jquery, dynamic, slide, fade

I have used this [example](http://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/) to create dynamic page effect. Here is the [demo](http://sudojesse.github.io/dynamic-page/). I want to make that page transition to slide left to right instead of fade in and fade out. How to get the slide effect?

Comment: Hi, post your current code and we'll modify it somehow. Usually it will require some additional DOM manipulations

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/z4Fwv/